# Sencha Touch: perform read (load) operation from singleton model

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, senchatouch-2.4

I have a singleton model and an associated AJAX proxy.

If I make a call to MyModel.load(), I get the error:

`MyModel.load is not a function`

However, you do have load in Model:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-static-method-load

On the contrary, MyModel.save() exists and I can access it.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load` method listed on `Ext.data.Model` is a static method on the class definition, **not** an instance. The documentation even denotes this is a static method. When you want to load a record, you don't load an already instantiated record, you load the model definition and that loading creates an instance.

The `save` method listed on `Ext.data.Model` is an instance method, the docs do not denote this as a static method. You don't save a class definition, you save an instance.

Example usage: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lvj

Comment: thanks for clarifying and for the example, I have completely missed the static label